# writing ITK label data to file in the fastest possible way

Tags: file, optimization, ofstream, itk

I am stuck in a nasty optimization problem in my CT analysis software. I use ITK to perform some heavy filtering on the data, and finally by using the itk binaryImageToshapeLabelMapFilter i isolate some separate regions and save the coordinates of each point belonging to them to a text file (that is then going to be the input of another separate software already made)

The problem is, that the phase of writing to file, takes, in case of very large regions, much longer than the filtering itself (I happened to have some datasets filtered in 30 minutes and wrote to file in another additional hour).

In the following code, I already tried to avoid flushing at the end of each line ("\n" instead than endl) but nothing seems to change. Do you have any idea on how i could massively improve the write to file of this data?

Regards,
Emiliano

```
ofstream outFile;
string labelsFile = subFolderPath+"/regionLabels_"+volumeCompleteName+".lri";
outFile.open(labelsFile.c_str());
outFile << "LabelIndexes - v1.0" << "\n";
outFile << "Dataset Origin : "<< originX << "," << originY << "," << originZ << "\n";

int cloud = 0;

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < binaryImageToShapeLabelMapFilter->GetOutput()->GetNumberOfLabelObjects(); i++){
    BinaryImageToShapeLabelMapFilterType::OutputImageType::LabelObjectType* labelObject = binaryImageToShapeLabelMapFilter->GetOutput()->GetNthLabelObject(i);
    if(labelObject->GetNumberOfPixels()>4500){
        outFile << "Region " << cloud << "\n";
        outFile << "Centroid " << labelObject->GetCentroid() << "\n";
        outFile << labelObject->GetNumberOfPixels() << "\n";
        for(int j=0;j<labelObject->Size();j++){
            //Only save the labels for voxels at least 2 voxels distant from the edge of the dataset
            if(labelObject->GetIndex(j)[0]>2 && labelObject->GetIndex(j)[1]>2 && labelObject->GetIndex(j)[2]>2){
                if(labelObject->GetIndex(j)[0]<(maxX-2) && labelObject->GetIndex(j)[1]<(maxY-2) && labelObject->GetIndex(j)[2]<(maxZ-2)){
                    outFile << labelObject->GetIndex(j) << "\n";
                }
            }
        }
        cloud++;
    }
}
outFile << "EndOfFile" << "\n";
outFile.flush();
outFile.close();
cout << "All labels indices saved to file : " << labelsFile << endl;
```

One last additional question. I didn't have time to try with the dataset i already filtered with the older method, but the last 2 i filtered with the new one seems that half of each region is being lost. Am I misusing the indices by using it like this :

```
FILE* fout = fopen(labelsFile.c_str(), "w");
fprintf(fout,"LabelIndexes - v1.0\n");
fprintf(fout,"Dataset Origin : %d,%d,%d\n",originX,originY,originZ);

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < binaryImageToShapeLabelMapFilter->GetOutput()->GetNumberOfLabelObjects(); i++){
    BinaryImageToShapeLabelMapFilterType::OutputImageType::LabelObjectType* labelObject = binaryImageToShapeLabelMapFilter->GetOutput()->GetNthLabelObject(i);
    if(labelObject->GetNumberOfPixels()>4500){
        fprintf(fout,"Region %d \n",cloud);
        double c1 = labelObject->GetCentroid()[0];
        double c2 = labelObject->GetCentroid()[0];
        double c3 = labelObject->GetCentroid()[0];
        fprintf(fout,"Centroid [%f, %f, %f]\n",c1,c2,c3);
        fprintf(fout,"%u\n",(long)labelObject->GetNumberOfPixels());
        for (int l = 0; l < labelObject->GetNumberOfLines(); ++l){
             LabelObjectLine<3> line = labelObject->GetLine(l);
             OutputImageType::IndexType startIndex = line.GetIndex();
             int i1 = startIndex[0];
             int i2 = startIndex[1];
             int i3 = startIndex[2];
             if(i1>2 && i2>2 && i3>2 && i1<(maxX-2) && i2<(maxY-2) && i3<(maxZ-2))fprintf(fout,"[%d, %d, %d]\n",i1,i2,i3);
         }
         cloud++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try profiling you code? That will likely tell you where the computation time is going.

However, I think it's going into the **numerous** calls to labelObject::GetIndex. If you look at the implementation of LabelObject::GetIndex you can see it's on the order of the number of lines in the label object. You are calling it 7 time per index. Just save the results of this function call into a variable will give you an 7x speedup.

However lets look a the computational cost of the loop! The loop is over the number of indexes in the label object, and then the multiplication factor of the GetIndex call. This results in the order of the computation being significantly grater that the number of indexes in the label object.

A better approach would be to use the LabelObject::GetLine method and a line based algorithm:

```
 for (l = 0; l < labelObject.GetNumberOfLines(); ++l)
   line = labelObject.GetLine(l)
   startIndex = line.GetIndex();
   endIndex = startIndex;
   endIndex[0] = endIndex[0] + line.GetLength() - 1
   // determine which indexes to print.
```

The will reduce the computational complexity down to the the number of lines. It would not surprise me if this took less than a minute with this apporach.

Comment: I will try immediately, yesterday I tried to rewrite it all in C (fprintf, etc) and buffering the indices too, but the results where not much more encouraging. I will let you know asap! Thanks!

Comment: You absolutely made my day with this solution. And my making my last day before one week holiday you made me seriously happier and more relaxed! we went indeed down to less than 1 minute. Cheers!

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with what may yield your missing regions. However you c1,c2,c3 variable are not being set correctly.

Comment: i see the centroid where i forgot to change the index, thanks. i have the feeling that for each line i only print the first index. now back to work even if it's saturday, i will try to fix that, thx. It is quite difficult to find detailed documentation and examples about several "niche" ITK features.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I was misusing the indices, blowekamp solution was otherwise optimal. Here's the working version of the loop (took some nasty debugging to get the problem) :

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < binaryImageToShapeLabelMapFilter->GetOutput()->GetNumberOfLabelObjects(); i++){
        BinaryImageToShapeLabelMapFilterType::OutputImageType::LabelObjectType* labelObject = binaryImageToShapeLabelMapFilter->GetOutput()->GetNthLabelObject(i);
        if(labelObject->GetNumberOfPixels()>4500){
            fprintf(fout,"Region %d \n",cloud);
            double c1 = labelObject->GetCentroid()[0];
            double c2 = labelObject->GetCentroid()[1];
            double c3 = labelObject->GetCentroid()[2];
            fprintf(fout,"Centroid [%f, %f, %f]\n",c1,c2,c3);
            fprintf(fout,"%u\n",(long)labelObject->GetNumberOfPixels());
            for (int l = 0; l < labelObject->GetNumberOfLines(); ++l){
                 LabelObjectLine<3> line = labelObject->GetLine(l);
                 OutputImageType::IndexType startIndex = line.GetIndex();
                 long lastIndex = startIndex[0]+line.GetLength();
                 for(OutputImageType::IndexType idx = startIndex;idx[0]<lastIndex;idx[0]++){
                     int i1 = idx[0];
                     int i2 = idx[1];
                     int i3 = idx[2];
                     if(i1>2 && i2>2 && i3>2 && i1<(maxX-2) && i2<(maxY-2) && i3<(maxZ-2))fprintf(fout,"[%d, %d, %d]\n",i1,i2,i3);
                 }
            }
            cloud++;
        }
    }
fprintf(fout,"EndOfFile");
fclose(fout);
```